# Move all text over

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I want to move all my text over by a certain amount, I do not want it to be centered. What would I add or fix to my code to make that possible? I want the h2, h3, and p to be aligned to where the h2 currently is next to the menu. I am sorry if you could not understand what I am trying to ask. Thanks ahead of time.

```css
body
     {
     background-color:#333;
     color:#999
     font: 12px/1.4em Arial,sans-serif;
     }
    #wrap
     {
     margin-left: 10px auto;
     background: black;
     padding:10px;
     width: 100px;
     float:left;
     }
    #header
     {
     background-color:black;
     color: #fff;
     }
    #logo
     {
     float: center;
     font-size: 30px;
     line-height:0px;
     padding: 5px;
     }
    #navWrap
     {
     height:50px;
     float:center;
     }
    #nav ul
     {
     margin: 1px;
     padding:1px;
     float:left;
     }
    #nav li
     {
     float:left;
     padding: 5px;
     background-color: black;
     margin: 0 5px;
     color: white;
     list-style-type: none
     }
    #nav li a
     {
     color:white;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 15px;
     float:left;
     text-indent:0px;
     }
    #nav li a:hover
     {
     text-decoration: underline;
     float:left;
     }
    br.clearLeft
     {
     clear: left;
     }
    h1
     {
     color:cyan;
     text-align:center;
     border-bottom: double 5px;
     }
    h2
     {
     color:red;
     }
    h3
     {
     color:cyan;
     }
    p
     {
     color:#DBDBDB;
     font-size:22px;
     }
```

```html
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="logo"></div>
                <div id="navWrap">
                    <div id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="x" ; class="smothScroll">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="xl" ; class="smothScroll">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="x" ; class="smothScroll">My Tumblr</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h2>x</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>x</p>
        <p>x</br>xe</br>x</br>Lx</p>
        <p>Rxy</br>x</br>x</br>x</p>
        <p>Rx</br>x x</br>x</br>x</p>
        <p>x</br>xarex</br>Ix</br>M</p>
```

Comment: some HTML markup might help!

Comment: HTML please?? also if possible jsfiddle, works fast for us.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry about that:

Comment: sorry about the messy html^

Comment: @Kevril You can edit your original question to include the updated code. That way you can properly format it and it's much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a padding to `body` like

```
body { 
  padding-left: 120px; 
  /* this "moves" the content inside body 120px to the right (120 = 100 + padding 2*10) */
}
```

If you need your `wrap` element where it is now, just add a negative margin then

```
#wrap {
  margin-left: -110px; 
  /* -90px because it was originally 10px, so you need to substract 120px from that */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css :

```
position:relative
```

And then the attributes top,left,bottom and right to move the element the way you want like :

```
position:relative;
bottom:10px;
top:5px;
```

Look at this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/ha7e7wz1/